# Office 365 - Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, visual-web-part, sandbox-solution

In Office 365 environment, I have received the below error while submitting the form which was developed by Sandboxed Solution.

> Web Part Error : Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

Code:

```
SPList List = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["List Name"]; 
SPListItem Listitem = List.Items.Add(); 
Listitem["Title"] = "First"; 
Listitem["Status"] = "Submit"; 
Listitem.Update(); 
List.Update();
```

Advise me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: SPList List = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["List Name"];
SPListItem Listitem = List.Items.Add();
Listitem["Title"] = "First";
Listitem["Status"] = "Submit";
Listitem.Update();
List.Update();

Comment: Asad, i have shared the code above. Thanks in advance if u have any solution...